# How to split string into an array into two separate strings

Tags: ruby, split

I have the following Ruby on Rails `params`:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"type"=>["abc, def"], "format"=>:json, "controller"=>"order", "action"=>"index"} permitted: false>
```

I want to check if there's a `,` in the string, then separate it into two strings like below and update `type` in `params`.

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"type"=>["abc", "def"], "format"=>:json, "controller"=>"order", "action"=>"index"} permitted: false>
```

I tried to do like below:

```
params[:type][0].split(",") #=> ["abc", " def"]
```

but I am not sure why there's a space before the second string.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Just strip the array - `params[:type][0].split(",").compact.collect(&:strip) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there's a whitespace in your string, that's why the result of using split will also include it in the splitted element for the array.

You could remove first the whitespaces and then use split. Or add `', '` as the split value in order it takes the comma and the space after it. Or depending on the result you're trying to get, to map the resulting elements in the array and remove the whitespaces there, like:

```
string = 'abc, def'
p string.split ','              # ["abc", " def"]
p string.split ', '             # ["abc", "def"]
p string.delete(' ').split ','  # ["abc", "def"]
p string.split(',').map &:strip # ["abc", "def"]
```

Comment: `delete(' ')` will remove all space characters from the string, not just the extra whitespace. `p string.split(",").map(&:strip)` would be a better option, though `split(', ')` is the best case scenario if it's possible to use.

Comment: @Sebastian Palma. Thanks. I just realized what if i have 3 values e.g ["abc, def, ""], last one is a blank value. can i also separate it. i tried but it gives me `["abc", "def", "\"\""]`

Comment: You could use `string.split(', ')`, `string.delete(' ').split(',')` or to reject the empty values in the array `string.split(',').map(&:strip).reject &:empty?`.